# Will Earth at some point stop rotating anti-clockwise, stay still, and then rotate clockwise?

Tags: earth, rotation

Will Earth at some point stop rotating anti-clockwise, stay still, and then rotate clockwise?

Comment: Can you add some more context to this question?  Like why you would think this is possible.

Comment: No, there is no known phenomenon what could cause this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No. This would require some force imposed externally. Momentum is a wonderful thing.

Comment: ...some torque about the Earth's axis...

Comment: Maybe if one of the larger [centaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centaur_(minor_planet)) gets perturbed into the inner system and Earth gets unlucky enough to suffer an oblique impact? Not sure that would count as "stay still and then rotate clockwise" though.